# How does DataSource test in cakephp 2

Tags: php, cakephp

We have custom DataSource and want to test that verifies the data after find method execute equals to one not customized.As I thought it, it would be possible if we can change Datasource in test code.I try many case, but I couldn't make it work.

```
 public $default = [
    'datasource' => 'CustomPostgres',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => '5432',
    'login' => 'hoge',
    'password' => 'hogehoge',
    'database' => 'prod',
    'schema' => 'public',
    'prefix' => '',
    'encoding' => 'utf8'
];

public $test = [
    'datasource' => 'CustomPostgres',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => '5432',
    'login' => 'hoge',
    'password' => 'hogehoge',
    'database' => 'test_prod',
    'schema' => 'public',
    'prefix' => '',
    'encoding' => 'utf8'
];

public $old = [
    'datasource' => 'Database/Postgres',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => '5432',
    'login' => 'hoge',
    'password' => 'hogehoge',
    'database' => 'dev',
    'schema' => 'public',
    'prefix' => '',
    'encoding' => 'utf8'
];

public $test_old = [
    'datasource' => 'Database/Postgres',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => '5432',
    'login' => 'hoge',
    'password' => 'hogehoge',
    'database' => 'test_dev',
    'schema' => 'public',
    'prefix' => '',
    'encoding' => 'utf8'
];

//try1
$this->Model->setDataSource('test_old');
//try2
ConnectionManage::create('test_old',///);
//try3
////in fixture File and ClassRegistry:Init("Model")
$useDbConfig = "old";
////inner start::up
ClassRegistry:Init("Model");
//try4 extends model
ModelForOldSetting extends Model{
  $useDbConfig = "old";
}
```

Above codes didn't work and it always emit error says
MissingConnectionException: Database connection "Postgres" is missing, or could not be created ,when running test however it works fine when setting default datasource Database/Postgres running local browser without test.

So, I'm really confused why Database connection "Postgres" is missing.Any idea makes me appreciate to them.

Comment: What is your Postgres version ?

Comment: @Kevin Kyaw My postgresql version is 9.6.4 and I found why it causes. I'm sorry that it is not cakephp problem and causes by stupid application structure of our project.Thank you for trying to advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found irritating and stupid irritating code by outer database.php file overrides datasources' setting.Following code works fine after appropriate settings.

```
ModelForOldSetting extends Model{
  $useDbConfig = "dev";
  $useTables = "models";
}

ClassRegistry:Init("ModelForOldSetting");
$model = $this->getMockForModel('ModelForOldSetting');
```